How to Close Strip Save Feature Payment Method ReactNative
enter image description here
There Any way hide Strip [Save Feature Payment Method]
No need to save Payment in feature use
Already Try
setup_future_usage='off_session'
automatic_payment_methods={"enabled": false},
